# Fix array not properly being assigned

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign a specific part of an array a new value, but it doesn't seem to be inserting the new value into the array.

```
char matrix[20][8] = {/*160 * '#'*/};

void Draw() {
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Welcome to Primitive Pong v1.0!" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
}

while (gameOver == false) {
    matrix[10][4] = 'O';
    Draw();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

I expect this to output a grid of 160 "#" with a "O" near the middle, but instead it just prints 160 "#". I am trying to make a game of console pong. I have tried using 'matrix[10][4] = {'O'};, but that does nothing different.

Comment: Your matrix has 20 rows 8 columns but your Draw function accesses 20 columns.

Comment: I stared at this code for like 20 minutes and didn't notice that lmao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `matrix[20][8]` but then you access it as if its dimensions are `[8][20]` instead.

The total is the same but the access doesn't work correctly and, unfortunately, C++ will not check about this kind of mistake. Changing the code to

```
        cout << matrix[j][i] << " ";
```

should make things work a you expect.